# Solve the recurrence relation: $a_n = 6a_{n-1} - 9a_{n-2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Recurrence relation:$$a_n = 6a_{n-1} - 9a_{n-2}$$

Initial conditions:$$a_1 = 1, a_2 = 9$$

I am having a bit of trouble finishing off this problem. So far I have:

Assume:$$a_n = r^n$$

$$r^n = 6r^{n-1}-9r^{n-2}$$
$$r^2 = 6r - 9$$
$$r^2 - 6r + 9 = 0$$
$$(r-3)^2 = 0$$
This means:
$$a_n = A(3)^n+B(n3^n)$$
$$a_1 = A3^1 + B((1)3^1) = 3A + 3B = 1$$
$$a_2 = A3^2 + B((2)3^2) = 9A + 18B = 9$$

From there I can't seem to combine the equations to find out what A and B are equal to correctly. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
9-3\times 1 &=a_2-3a_1 \\
6 &= (9A+18B)-(9A+9B) \\
6 &= 9B
\end{align}$$
Therefore $B=\frac 23$, substitute this into $A_1$ yields
$$
3A=1-3B=1-3\times(\frac 23)=1-2=-1
$$ 
so that $A=-\frac 13$, thus
$$
A=-\frac 13, B=\frac 23
$$

Comment: I see it now. Thanks! Just to clarify...
can the top part (9-3 X 1) of this be used on all similar cases? (adjusting the numbers accordingly of course)

Comment: Yes. In general if the equations are of the form $$ax+by=c \\
dx+ey=f$$
you can multiply the first one entirely by $d$, the second by $a$ to get 
$$
adx+bdy=cd \\
adx+aey=af
$$ 
then subtract them to eliminate $x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Another Method.**
Note that $$a_n - 3a_{n-1} = 3(a_{n-1} - 3 a_{n-2})$$ for $n\geq 2$, so the sequence $(b_n)_{n\geq 2}$ defined by
$$
  b_n = a_n - 3a_{n-1}\quad\text{and}\quad b_2 = a_2-3a_1 = 6
$$ is geometric with common ratio $r=3$. Thus, for all $n\geq 2$, we have
$$b_n = b_2 r^{n-2} = 6\times 3^{n-2}.$$
Now,
$$
  \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} 3^k b_{n-k} = \sum_{k=2}^{n-2} (3^ka_{n-k} - 3^{k+1}a_{n-k-1})
$$
where the right side is a telescoping series. Simplifying we get
$$
  6(n-1)\times 3^{n-2} = a_n - 3^{n-1},
$$
and finally
$$
  a_n = (2n-1)3^{n-1}.
$$